# Making a toggle switch

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

How do I make a toggle switch with the button starting a the middle position. Then on click will animate the left position property so that the button will be on the left. Clicking a second time will reset the position back the middle. Clicking a third time will move the button the right. And clicking a fourth time will move it back to the middle.

HTML

```
<div class="toggle">
<div class="toggle-item bg"></div>
<div class="toggle-item button"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.toggle{
position: relative;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
width: 342px;
}

.toggle-item{
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
}

.button{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
left: 75px;
background-color: red;
}

.bg{
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
background-color: #000;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cjymyzg6/

Ideally I would like to assign a variable because I plan to use this as a filter for an Isotope grid

Comment: Where's your Javascript?

Comment: If you show what progress you've made so far on writing the javascript you'll be much more likely to get positive feedback and help from this community...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
var pos = 1;
$('.toggle').click(function(){
    if(pos === 1){
        $('.button').css('left', '0');
    }else if(pos === 2){
        $('.button').css('left', '75px');
    }else if(pos === 3){
        $('.button').css('left', '150px');
    }else if(pos === 4){
        $('.button').css('left', '75px');
        pos = 0;
    }
    pos++;
});
```

The variable `pos` save the current position. Also I add a CSS transition.

See working here: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/cjymyzg6/2/